# Connecting Trailer module (TRM) for Volvo V70 2005

Tags: electrical, volvo, trailer

I'm going to install a [Trailer module](http://www.skandix.de/en/spare-parts/accessories/car-accessories/load-carry/towbar-parts/control-unit-tow-bar-trailermodul-trm/1019465/) (TRM) into a Volvo V70 2005. There are are two sockets on it (a gray and a green one). I found the cable from the [Rear electrical module](https://www.myvolvoparts.com/Genuine-Volvo-REM-Rear-Electronic-Module-S60-S80-V70-XC70-XC90_p_20650.html) (REM) which should be connected to the gray socket on the TRM. But I also found two cables with similar green connectors. I think the one with 5 wires should go into the green socket of the TRM, but where should the other go? [image: Connectors for TRM]

Comment: Where is the other green connector? Show all three and then we may be able to work it out...

Comment: @SolarMike I can't find any third connector in the reach of the two cables in the picture. And both of them individually fits in the green socket on the TRM.

Comment: Since all these items apparently need a software download from a Volvo dealer, that's would be the obvious place to find out which cables go where. Alternatively, you need a circuit diagram. The green connectors obviously have different purposes since they connect different numbers of wires.

Comment: @SolarMike I think the OP means the green socket on the panel of the trailer module in the picture. It's impossible to see what it's connected to unless you can take the trailer module case off somehow.

Comment: I can see two green plugs but don't see a socket anywhere - which I hoped to see just in case there was some clue with the number of pins...

Comment: @SolarMike I've updated the question a little. I've opened the TRM case and found there are four wires. I also studied picture online, and it seems its the one with 5 wires (in my picture) that should go into the TRM. So, then I'm left with the other one in the picture. I can't see any connector for it in the car.

Comment: Why assume that other socket must be used? I found several unused sockets in the back end of my car... sat nag, premium stereo amp etc etc

Comment: @SolarMike Good point. It might be for a possible CD changer or something. I don't know, but it would be interesting to know. I will test the other one (5 wired) in the TRM and see if it works.